# Rails migration: update_all with dynamic code is possible?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations, update-all

I'd like to add a new field in a table.

My new "secret_code" field in my User model should be equal to Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)[1..12].

What I'm trying to do is generate a migration that would add the field to the table and also populate my existing users with a (sort of) unique "secret_code".

```
class AddSecretCodeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :secret_code, :string
    User.update_all ["secret_code =?", Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)[1..12]]
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :secret_code
  end
end
```

The problem is that this migration populate all the existing users with the same secret code!

One solution would be NOT to use update_all and run a loop to fetch every user and send an update to each one, but in this case my migration would be extremely slow.

Is there a way to send a "unique" random value to an update_all method?

Thanks,
Augusto

Comment: Mysql on developement and postgres on production

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing it to `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].to_s)` but personally I'd create a rake task to the above as it's not really a migration.

Your rake task would do

```
User.all.each do |u|
  u.update_attribute(:secret_code, Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].to_s))
end
```

However, for your migration I'd also add `t.string :secret_code, :default => Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].to_s)`
 to the attribute so that it is added on newly created records.

Comment: Thanks, but does update_attribute skip callbacks?  Otherwise it woul be extremely slow..

Comment: You could also just do `User.update_all(:secret_code => Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].to_s))` in your rake task instead then =)

Comment: Since you can not do exactly what you are asking to do anywhere other than code, you have to execute a command for each User. This will be slow no matter what you do :( If you look at @[mu is too short]'s answer, he has a way to make it fast but you are doing something completely different.

Comment: Cheers for the clarification Travis!

Answer (score 3):

For MySQL, you could throw this right in your `self.up`:

```
connection.execute(%Q{
    update users
    set secret_code = substring(sha1(rand()) from 1 for 12)
})
```

PostgreSQL doesn't have SHA1 support by default but it does have MD5 and that's probably good enough for this:

```
connection.execute(%Q{
    update users
    set secret_code = substring(md5(random()::varchar) from 1 for 12)
})
```

If you have the [pgcrypto](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html) package installed then you could use SHA1 for both.

Both of those will let the database do all the work and avoid all the overhead of round-tripping your whole table. You can play around with what you hash a bit as well, if you wanted to mix the time in:

```
md5(random()::varchar || now()::varchar) -- PostgreSQL
sha(rand()            || now()         ) -- MySQL
```